# Can I board my flight from an intermediary city?

Tags: air-travel, airport-transfer

My return flight takes the following path: Ottawa - Montreal - Frankfurt - Toulouse. The companies are Air Canada from Ottawa to Frankfurt and Lufthansa for the last flight.

I plan on visiting Montreal in my last days in Canada. Can I depart from Montreal instead of Ottawa without any trouble?

Comment: No, you cannot. You absolutely need to change your ticket in advance and might be charged for it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, if you don't show up at the first flight, without notifying the airline, then your ticket will be cancelled also for the other flights.

You can call the airline and notify them about your plan, probably they could modify your ticket or do something about it.

Comment: Do I need to pay additional fees for this or it depends on the airline?

Comment: usually when you modify a reservation you always pay something. But it depends on the airline and on the specific reservation made. Sometimes first or second modifications are for free and you pay just the ticket price difference.